# Does anyone know how to upgrade existing project from Sencha Ext JS 4.2 to newest Sencha Ext JS version please?

Tags: javascript, extjs, upgrade

I have got a huge javascript project using Sencha Ext JS. But it is only version 4.2. I would like to upgrade it to at least version 7.0. I have been following some official documentation of Sencha, but none of provided tutorials have helped me. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: If you already tried, can you provide us with, what and what is says, why it's not working? From my point of view, I would suggest you to read all different updates and check if this is for you and if you have to take actions for that update (eg. 5, 5.5., 6.0, 6.2, 6.5, 6.6, 7.0, 7.2)

Comment: read there release documentation

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the cmd command **sencha app upgrade [ path-to-new-framework ]**?